# Random OpenGL freeze on Android with Adreno GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I got a strange random OpenGL error when my app runs on the Android devices with Adreno GPU. This issue could be reproduced on Android 4.X and 5.X and it only happens on Adreno GPU.

```
E/Surface (14388): dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer    failed: -2147483646
W/Adreno-EGLSUB(14388): <DequeueBuffer:720>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
W/Adreno-EGL(14388): <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3702>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
W/GLThread(14388): eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
W/OpenGLRenderer(14388): swapBuffers encountered EGL_BAD_SURFACE on 0xaf43d340, halting rendering...
```

My app freezes when the error happens. It is a pure native application written in C/C++. The only view in my app is a subclass of GLSurfaceView.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue? Any clue would be great helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think finally I found the reason.

My app opens to many files thus the limit IO handles, say about 1024, is exhausted. On the other hand it seems the Adreno driver need to require some more IO handles when swapping buffer and then cause the app freezing.

And this issue has been resolved by manually invoke `System.gc()` after the files are closed.

UPDATES

I passed a FileDescriptor, via `openFd`, to the `SoundPool.load`. However, the `SoundPool.unload` doesn't release that FD which it used. I have to hold a reference to the FD myself and close it when `SoundPool.onLoadComplete`

Comment: It's better to explicitly close the files when they're no longer needed, rather than waiting for a Java-language destructor to close them. The Android system code uses a "close guard" that complains when an object with a file descriptor gets GCed while the file is still open.

Comment: What I mean is I have already closed the files but I still need to call System.gc() to take effect.

Comment: `System.gc()` cleans up the Java-language objects on the managed heap. It knows nothing about non-memory resources like files or network connections. The only way it would close a file is if the object with the file descriptor had a finalizer that did the actual close.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Finally I found the leak was caused by the SoundPool.  I passed a FileDescriptor, via 'openFd', to the "SoundPool.load". However, the "SoundPool.unload" doesn't release that FD which it used. I have to hold a reference to the FD myself and close it when   "SoundPool.onLoadComplete"

Comment: Thanks for the information that hardware or driver is probably at fault. I got the same message under load on a tablet that was supposed to be new. The load (on main thread) was my app's fault, but as far as I can see it is just perfectly legitimate CPU,